# Windows 10 monitor display settings position upon disable/enable

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have setup a script that allows me to enable/disable a monitor of mine on the fly using Nirsofts MultiMonitorTool. The problem is, when I re-enable a monitor its position inside the display settings seems to reset from where I place it. I'll put the monitor here:

[image: intended position]

but after disabling it and re-enabling it with the tool it will appear here:

[image: unintended position]

If you can't see the images, just know that it's not where I want it.

If anyone has experience with this tool or knows a way to glue a monitor position in place i'd be forever grateful.